# Mostrar diferentes paneles en un mismo formulario con c#

Tags: c#

Hola estoy intentando crear diferentes paginas en un mismo formulario digamos que tendré varios labels como el siguiente:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces cuando le de a Main el panel será blanco. Pero cuando le de a label1, el panel será oscuro como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código será simplemente un formulario como este:

```
namespace Espacio
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Form1Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

En definitiva tendré dos paneles. Cuando le de al label Main -> me mostrará mi primer panel. Cuando le de a label2 -> me mostrará mi segundo panel.

Con tab me queda de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que quiero es que tab1 tab2 este a la izquierda por eso uso paneles y labels. Lo que no entiende es como superponer un panel a otro segun el label que clikee para que me lo cambie y me muestre otro.

Comment: y cual es el problema?

Comment: que cuando pongo `void MainClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         
        }` No se como hacer para que el panel 1 se vea en lugar del panel2.

Comment: objeto.Visibility = Visibility.Visible?

Comment: utilizar `Tabs` no te funciono?

Comment: intente usar tabs pero me quedan en horizontal y quería en vertical. En cuanto a lo de visibility me recomiendas poner el panel 2 invisible y el 1 visible ¿ puede ser eso ? Esque voy a tener varios label's y usar diferentes paneles y no sé que pueda ser mejor si tabs o esto que estaba intentando porque los tabs me quedaban subo una captura como me quedaba.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404305(v=vs.110).aspx google sabe.. igual no es recomendable eso..

Comment: ¿Estás intentando cambiar el tab según el label al que haces click? ¿O quieres mostrar paneles superpuestos según el label al que le haces click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que tienes es un panel sobre otro bastaría con ocultar o mostrar el segundo panel según le des a un label o al otro. Algo así:

```
private void BtnVerPanel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel2.Hide();
    }
    private void btnVerPanel2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel.Show();
    }
```

Otra opcion es que quieras hacer algo como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que suponiendo que usas WPF seria algo así:

```
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="299" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497" TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

La parte importante seria `TabStripPlacement="Left"`

Si lo que utilizas en WindowsForm, como parece, pues la solución que te indica @gbianchi en su comentario parece que funciona. O si no puedes poner algo así cambiando la propiedad `this.tabControl1.Alignment = TabAlignment.Left;` Quedando visualmente algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo y espero que alguna de estas cosas te funcione.